# SQL Interactive File Path

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way in SQL server to interact to a folder on my computer?

I have this file path:

`'Y:\300 ORDER PROCESSING\Majid Ahmadi\Custom Cabs\' + 'CUSTOM' + '_'  + CAST (olnav.olnavValue as nvarchar(25)) +  '.jpg'`

But with this I am only picking specific files in the folder. I want to be able to pick all the file in the folder regardless of the name. IS that possible?

Comment: What are you trying to do with said file?

Comment: I am trying to pick and use them on Crystal Report

Comment: Are you trying to read all file names from a folder with a query?

Comment: yes. but name of the files in folder can not be predicted.

Comment: That is really not easy to do with t-sql. The easiest way to do this is with CLR.

Comment: [Here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic851684-392-1.aspx) is a solution using `xp_cmdshell`. Another idea might be using a .NET function via CLR integration.

Comment: How would I do this through CLR? I currently just gave it the formula that uses the address from SQL and pick the specific file in the folder.

Comment: @stickybit I appreciate your reply. could you please elaborate?

Comment: CLR is Common Language Runtime. It allows you to create a procedure in sql server that executes dotnet code. It is trivial in dotnet code to read all the files in a directory. The trick is in getting everything setup and registered correctly when you have never done that before. There are thousands of tutorials all over the internet for that.

Comment: For the `xp_cmdshell` solution I already gave you a link. For CLR integration maybe start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/introduction-to-sql-server-clr-integration) and search for other resources. Covering this here is too broad. Come back with a specific question should you encounter a problem with that.

Comment: Much appreciated guys!

Comment: You will probably have to use the UNC path for whatever server\folder "Y:" is mapped to